# How is self-reference usually handled in math?

Tags: logic, axioms, foundations

Define statements A and B:

A: “this statement” is Y

B: “this statement” is X

Assume I may combine statements using the logical operator “and”.

Define statement C:

C: A and B. (Meaning “C asserts A and B are both true”)

Replace the definitions of A and B into C:

C: (“this statement” is Y) and (“this statement” is X).

If “this statement” refers to “the current statement”, then "C is Y" and "C is X".

If Y and X were mutually exclusive, this contradicts: C is simultaneously something and its negation. In other words, "self-reference" and the the logical operator "and" can be problematic if the selves are distinct.

By limiting self-reference to the original definition you avoid that problem. In other words, disallow the notion of “the current statement” and only allow explicitly named labels. We could have defined A and B earlier as:

A: A is X

B: B is Y

Then, if X and Y are mutually-exclusive, C, having no claim of X or Y regarding itself, is consistent, since C asserts about A and B, not itself:

C: (A is X) and (B is Y)

Alternatively, by defining all self-reference qualities (Y and X earlier) to be equivalent, you also avoid the problem. (Meaning since X and Y are both self-referential qualities, then they must be the same thing.) “There’s only a single self” sort of thing. But then you cannot negate the self (which is a bit strange, now you have two types of truths, those that can be negated and those that cannot).

Another way to resolve the contradiction: the selves could relate to one another as a tree. Given that, when you assert X "and" Y in C from the example earlier, the "and" could be interpretted as intersect-ing (or unioning) parts of the tree. When you negate it, you are inverting the vertices in the set. Of course then the "self" is not a statement that is true or false, but a graph. So, perhaps, in general, if the "self" is not a true/false statement but some other mathematical object (such as a graph), then no contradiction.

How is self-reference usually handled in math?

Comment: There's the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic and [Gödel numbering](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering).

Comment: There's something to be said about what I've just mentioned but I am finding it difficult to articulate.

Comment: I consider Russell's paradox and its resolution the main method of dealing with logical self-reference in a mathematical way.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3643859/how-is-self-reference-usually-handled-in-math).

Comment: I would interpret "this statement" as a reference to A/B, but also ask for clarification. You can do a deep dive from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impredicativity, but the beauty of math is that each problem can be defined more precisely than that. With a properly defined problem You never has to ask "if this refers to".

Answer (score 3):

A rigorous treatment of what you're doing needs a [metalanguage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalanguage) to describe statements in an "object language". [It can be shown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski's_undefinability_theorem) that consistency of the object language is equivalent (if it's sufficiently rich) to its lacking a [truth predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_predicate) for its own statements, so defining a uniform notion of truth has to be done in the metalanguage instead.

Comment: Will the metalanguage also lack a truth predicate for its own statements?

Comment: @WordsLikeJared Turtles all the way down, yes.